# Error in sentence - Incoherent relative clause?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Law may well contain within its arsenal of argument and decisionmaking
>   the resources it needs to adapt to a changing world, but insofar
>   as that is the case, it is even less likely that **the image of a totally closed
>   system** `in which existing rules of law—and maybe even the existing practices
>   of legal argument` —**will be an accurate picture of what law does and
>   how it does it**.

Isn't a predicate missing? I'm assuming the bolded as the subject and predicate. If so, then what's the predicate for "`in which existing .. of legal argument`"? What might I have misconstrued?

By the bye, I read the meta question about use of ; please allow me to use it here because this website doesn't support colour, yet I want to distinguish with it.

Source: P6, Thinking like a Lawyer, Frederick Schauer

Comment: Please cite source of quote

Comment: @jwpat7 Done. Sorry for the forgetfulness.

Comment: In English, we do not abbreviate *page* using a capital **P** prefixed to a number without a space.  We sometimes use “p. 6”, but for just two more characters, you could actually say what it means and make it easier to read by so doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is wrong. Not only is the sentence too convoluted to be readable even in a second attempt, but either the relative clause or its superordinate clause lacks a finite verb. Convoluted as the sentence is, it isn't worth anyone's time to try to reconstruct a valid relative or superordinate clause.

I also wonder about the use of *law* without an article: who wrote this? In addition to the convolution, there are other terms and phrases that do not suggest a very high quality of writing.

Comment: For reference, superordinate clause @ http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/super.htm and finite verb @ http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/finite.htm